# Scipy Minimize Ignores the Constraints

Tags: scipy, constraints, minimize, mle

I want to estimate the parameters of a model using maximum-likelihood method. The model has 6 parameters A, n, B, w1, w2, and w3 and I know that the true values of them are 180, 0.5, 1.5, 0.35, 0.45, and 0.2, respectively.
w1, w2, and w3 should be between 0 and 1; Also, w1+w2+w3=1. I added a constraint for the sum of w1, w2, and w3 but the code just ignores my constraint. can anyone please help me?
[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TEoAVgjYrxvwEzox8S_PP9GUGAh63fDj/view?usp=sharing) is my dataset and below is my code.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

n1 = df['drops']
def MLE(params):
    SI=10
    B = params[0]
    A = params[1]
    n = params[2]
    w1 = params[3]
    w2 = params[4]
    w3 = params[5]
    F=df['failure']
    SI1=w1*df['SIs1']+w2*df['SIs2']+w3*df['SIs3']
    nu=n1*(SI1/SI)**n
    PDF = (B*nu**(B-1))/(A*SI**-n)**B
    R = np.exp(-(nu/(A*SI**-n))**B)
    logLik = np.log ((PDF**F)*R)
    return(-sum(logLik[:]))

start_pos = [1.5, 130, 0.20,0.3, 0.4, 0.2]
bnds = [(1,4), (100, 300),  (0.2, 1),(0,1),(0,1),(0,1)]
cons = ({'type': 'eq','fun' : lambda params: np.array([params[3]+params[4]+params[5]-1])})

results = minimize(MLE, start_pos, method='L-BFGS-B', constraints=cons, bounds=bnds)
print(str("B="+str(round(results.x[0],2))+", A="+str(round(results.x[1],2))+", 
n="+str(round(results.x[2],2))+", w1="+str(round(results.x[3],2))+", w2="+str(round(results.x[4],2))+", w3="+str(round(results.x[5],2))))
```

Comment: The access to your dataset is denied.

Answer (score 2):

The L-BFGS-B method doesn't support general constraints, it only supports simple bounds on the variables, so your code should usually raise a warning. You can use the `SLSQP` or `trust-constr` method instead. Note also that `SLSQP` is chosen automatically if you don't provide a method and your problem has bounds and constraints.

Comment: I made the dataset public. I do not get any warning with the L-BFGS-B method. The SLSQP method returns "Nan" values for all parameters and the trust-constr method gives an error (error: array must not contain infs or NaNs).

Comment: @H2H Please provide a **reproducible** example. Otherwise, it's hard to help. Your code snippet still misses some variables, e.g. what is `SI` inside your MLE function?

Comment: I just added the SI value. Thanks!

Comment: @H2H Which version of scipy are you using? With scipy 1.7.0, your code yields a warning: *RuntimeWarning: Method L-BFGS-B cannot handle constraints.* as expected. Using the SLSQP method, it works like a charm and gives the solution `array([1.23575493, 300.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0])`.

Comment: I am using scipy 1.7.2

Comment: The estimates should be close to 180, 0.5, 1.5, 0.35, 0.45, and 0.2. The SLSQP estimates are incorrect.

Comment: this was THE answer I was looking for